How to create typescript package that has Vue3 components
I have a project where I want to have a handful of custom plugins (packages) to be used in a Vue project. Each package exports a interface that contains some options as well as Vue components. How do I go about building / packaging it?
import WidgetModule from "..."; // the shared interface for all plugins

// Vue Components
import Config from "./Config/Config.vue";
import Control from "./Control/Control.vue";

const Module: WidgetModule = {
  configComponent: Config,
  controlComponent: Control,

  some options: [1,2,3],
  fullscreen: true,
};

export default Module;

When I call tsc, it doesn't build the vue files - I'm just not sure how to make this all build correctly so I can import the module to another project. Also - I'm not opposed to just sharing the non-built code as a npm package and let the main project do the building. But again not sure the best way to go here.

As a rule of thumb, it has to be bundled. In case you want to publish unbundled modules for some reason, use vue-tsc instead of tsc

@EstusFlask hmmm. I tried vue-tsc but came across a ton of errors because I use  the composition API and a lof of code in the setup function. Mostly due to using inject(). One of the warnings are "[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components."

You may not need this as bundling is ok in general. It needs to be investigated why the errors, vue-tsc itself shouldn't affect it in this way A possible cause is that there are multiple vue copies for some reason
